# source.uri should not be empty string

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to load image but console log showing alert like source.uri should not be an empty string like this
[image]

and here is my code of image on View in React

```
 <Button
          onPress={this._pickImage}
          title="Upload Image KTP"
        />
        <Image source={this.state.ImageKTP ? { uri: this.state.ImageKTP } : null} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
         <Button
          onPress={this._pickImage2}
          title="Upload Image Selfie"
        />
        <Image source={this.state.ImageSelfie ? { uri: this.state.ImageSelfie } : null}  style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
```

and here is the pickImage Code //PickImage 2 also same with this

```
_pickImage = async () => {
        await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL);
        const { cancelled, uri } = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
          allowsEditing: true,
          aspect: [4, 4],
          base64: true
        });
        if (!cancelled) {
          this.setState({ ImageKTP: uri }, () => {
            this.createFormData(uri);
          });
        }
      };
```

and this is createformdata

```
createFormData = async (uri) =>  {
        const {ImageKTP} = this.state;
        if(!ImageKTP) return;
        let apiUrl = 'http://192.168.0.20/Api/uploading.php?ImageKTP = ' +ImageKTP;
        let uriParts = uri.split('.');
        let fileType = uriParts[uriParts.length - 1];

  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('ImageKTP', {
    uri,
    name: `ImageKTP.${fileType}`,
    type: `image/${fileType}`,
  });


  console.log(ImageKTP);

  let options = {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      
    },
  };

  return fetch(apiUrl, options);
}
```

is something wrong in here?

Comment: What is the default value of ImageKTP in state?

Comment: ImageKTP : ' ' on this.state

Comment: constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          UserEmail: '',
          idcardnumber: '',
          placeofbirth: '',
          dateofbirth: '',
          Gender: '',
          Religion: '',
          ImageKTP: '',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting this because **ImageKTP** is empty initially. Try setting ImageKTP value to null initially instead of empty

or doing something like

```
{this.state.ImageKTP.length > 0 ? <Image source={{uri: this.state.ImageKTP }} /> : null }
```